# binding random XmlDataSource to a repeater with Xpath

Tags: asp.net, xml, data-binding, xpath, repeater

I'm creating page to put together a list of cinema trailers on an asp.net web page inside of a repeater.

The source of the data is an online XML feed.

To do this I'm binding the repeater as follows...

```
string XML_FEED_URL = "http://some-cinema-feed.com/comingsoon/";

XmlDataSource data_source = new XmlDataSource();
data_source.DataFile = XML_FEED_URL;
data_source.XPath = "/movies/movie[position() > 0 and position() < 3]";

this.moviePreciewsRepeater.DataSource = data_source;
this.moviePreciewsRepeater.DataBind();
```

The issue is that the length of the feed changes regularly and rather than selecting a range of movies with the XPATH (i.e. 1-3 in the XML) I need to select 3 totally random movies from the XML and bind this back to the repeater.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple and short solution :)

Comment: Besides @Dimitre's good answer, do note that in XPath `position() > 0` **is always true**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
data_source.XPath = 
    string.Format(@"/movies/movie[position() = {0} 
                               or position() = {1}
                               or position() = {2}
                                 ]",
                  random1, random2, random3);
```

where the variables `random1`, `random2` and `random3` are the random integers you have already calculated.